# Is this a correct json format for what I'm trying to achieve?

Tags: json

For a school project we need to create a home automation network. Our group wants to use the json format to configure nodes to work with each other. We want to link an address of a node to a specific button to certain leds on the node (each node in the network has 2 buttons and 2 leds, a red one and a green one). The json file I made looks as follows:

```
{
  "address": 123412 
  [
    {
      "buttonOne": "true"
      [
        {
          "green": "true",
          "red": "false"
        }
      ],

      "buttonTwo": "false"
      [
        {
          "green": "false",
          "red": "false"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I am new to json so what I want to know is: Is this the correct format for what I'm trying to achieve? Right now I want to be able to read out the address and find out what buttons are bound to what leds. In the example above "buttonOne" should be linked to the green led and "buttonTwo" should be disabled.

Comment: This isn't valid JSON. (You can use https://jsonlint.com/ to test for valid format.)

Comment: Aside from the JSON validity issue you currently have: Unfortunately, there's no way to give an objective answer to "is this the correct format" - there are lots of ways to model your data. I do wonder, though, what the purpose is of having an array of documents for each button, since your example only shows one document in each array. JSON is fairly flexible, and there is no single right way to construct a document.

Comment: Your arrays also need `keys`. 
`buttons: [ 
     { 
        "buttonOne": true, 
        "colours": [ 
            { "green": true}, 
            { "red": false} 
        ] 
     }
]` 
.. You can also use jsonviewer.stack.hu to have 2 different views

Comment: Also, you can use the boolean values `true` and `false`, instead of strings like "true" and "false"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to use it for single address. you can create a single JSON object as follows.

```
{
        "address": 123412,
        "buttonOne": {
            "on": true,
            "green": true,
            "red": false
        },
        "buttonTwo": {
            "on": false,
            "green": false,
            "red": false
        }
    }
```

Here I am assuming "on" property is used for representing the button ON/OFF state.

if you want to define it for multiple addresses. then you can define an JSON array of objects as follows.

```
[
    {
        "address": 123412,
        "buttonOne": {
            "on": true,
            "green": true,
            "red": false
        },
        "buttonTwo": {
            "on": false,
            "green": false,
            "red": false
        }
    },
    {
        "address": "nextAddress",
        "buttonOne": {
            "on": "some_value",
            "green": "some_value",
            "red": "some_value"
        },
        "buttonTwo": {
            "on": "some_value",
            "green": "some_value",
            "red": "some_value"
        }
    }
]
```